# grouping join query results

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I am trying to write a query that shows me all orders with their options. So far that's done, but when I try to group them by order id it just print a separate row for each option and not the order ID and all its option under it.

I am missing something but can't figure out what is it :)

Here is what I have

```
$sql = 'SELECT *
        FROM `order` RIGHT JOIN `order_option`
        on order.order_id=order_option.order_id
        where order_status_id = 2 
        group by order_option.order_option_id';

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    print "ID:{$row['order_id']}  <br> ".
         "OPTION NAME: {$row['name']} <br> ".
         "VALUE: {$row['value']} <br> ".
         "--------------------------------<br>";
} 
echo "Fetched data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);

?>

**UPDATE 1**
```

This is how the query worked now

```
SELECT 
  o.order_id, 
  o.name, 
  o.value, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(o.order_id, o.name, o.value SEPARATOR ',') AS Options 
FROM `order_option` AS o 
LEFT JOIN `order` AS oo on o.order_id = oo.order_id 
where oo.order_status_id = 2 
group by o.order_id
```

Comment: I can count the number of times I've seen RIGHT JOIN used (by someone who knew what they were doing) on the fingers of, well, two hands. For every RIGHT JOIN there is apparently a logically identical LEFT JOIN and, because LEFT JOINs tend to be more intuitive, we tend to use those instead.

Comment: Next, you have no aggregating functions anywhere in your query so GROUP BY cannot be doing whatever it is that you think it's doing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `GROUP BY order_id` instead, and use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get all the options of an order in the same row:

```
SELECT 
  o.order_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(oo.order_option_id SEPARATOR ',') AS Options
FROM `order` AS o
RIGHT JOIN `order_option` AS oo on o.order_id = oo.order_id
where o.order_status_id = 2 
group by o.order_id;
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7a8e/1)

If `GROUP_CONCAT` is not what are you looking for, then you have to use other aggregate functions, but don't include any columns that is not in the `GROUP BY` clause in the `SELECT` clause without an aggregate function. Otherwise you will got inconsistent data.

---

### Update 1

The reason your query doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
  o.order_id, 
  o.name, 
  o.value, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(o.order_id SEPARATOR ',') AS Options 
FROM order_option AS o 
LEFT JOIN order AS oo on o.order_id = oo.order_id 
where oo.order_status_id = 2 
group by o.order_id
```

Becuase the two columns `o.name, o.value` in the `SELECT` clause are not neither in an aggregate function not in the `GROUP BY` clause, so you are getting inconsistent values of these tow columns, MySQL gets an arbitrary value for them. Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
  o.order_id, 
  o.name, 
  o.value, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(o.order_id SEPARATOR ',') AS Options 
FROM order_option AS o 
LEFT JOIN order AS oo on o.order_id = oo.order_id 
where oo.order_status_id = 2 
group by o.order_id, 
         o.name,
         o.value;
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want I think... but cant manage with getting it grouped in the "while {" section of the code. I am missing something

Comment: @largan - Can you please update your code, and show how it is not working.

Comment: this is my code $sql = "SELECT 
  o.order_id, o.name, o.value,
  GROUP_CONCAT(o.order_id SEPARATOR ',') AS Options
  FROM `order_option` AS o
  LEFT JOIN `order` AS oo on o.order_id = oo.order_id
  where oo.order_status_id = 2 
  group by o.order_id";

$result = mysql_query($sql); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
$id=$row['order_id'];
$name=$row['name'];
$value=$row['value'];
print " $id name: $name, value: $value";

    PRINT "<br>-------------------<br>";
}

Comment: And this is the result ID 29 name: option1, value: 39

Comment: the problem is that there is option2 for every ID and is does not show

Comment: @largan Try `print $row[order_id]`, `print $row['options']` directly. Also have you tried this query directly in MySQL.

Comment: this is the result if I run it directly in SQL 
20 option1 value
21 option1 value
22 option1 value

Comment: @largan See my edit, I am not sure if this is what you are looking for or not. If not edit your question and explain it clearly with some sample data. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the hint... I manage it to work as desired. Just put the options in the GROUP_CONCAT and grouped only by o.order_id... then just printed the $options as you advised. Thanks a lot. See my update in the main post